# How can I ensure that my custom written C application runs at startup?

Tags: 10.04, startup, reboot, autostart, binary

I have written a command line C application that I need to run every time the system starts up. How would I go about doing this? I have seen other questions and answers that show ways to do this for pre-installed software via visual menus but this is just a custom written binary that I need to make sure runs after every reboot. Is there any way I can do this, or must I write a shell script that runs the binary and find a way to add that to the scripts that get run at startup? I am running on 10.04.

Comment: you have to run this app as root or as a normal user ?

Comment: my login is disabled so I autologin as myself and run as such - no running as root is needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this can run at the very end of the boot process, you can either just include it in `/etc/rc.local` or use the special cron `@reboot` parameter and put it in the user or system (root) crontab, depending on the privileges it needs.

Answer (score 2):

There are couple of ways. All based on what permission you require,

Easiest one is as follows,

The following is tutorial for 
 - Open startup applications from the power cog
[image: powercog]

Click on `ADD`

[image: add-button]

Then provide the details,

[image: add-dialog]

Comment: He said its a CLI system IIRC?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to execute something each time you are logged in you have to modify your local

```
~/.profile
```

If you want to execute something each time you start a login shell you can modify your

```
~/.bashrc
```

In you case you have to add your executable to `.profile` and drop a new line for it, remember to add a `&` at the end to run this application as a separate process.

Something like

```
/usr/bin/gedit &
```